# Break text file into separate words and store in array in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm trying to read a text file and then store its individual words in an array. But I can't find a way to split it according to words.

```
text_file = []

File.open(file, "r") do |f|
  f.lines.each do |line|
    text_file << line.split.map(&:to_s)
  end
end
```

The above method creates an array of arrays which stores all the words in a single line in an array and so on.

Is there a way in which the array `text_file` can hold a single array of all the words?

Comment: If the file is not huge, you could "gulp" it into a string, then apply [String#scan](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-scan): `File.read(FName).scan(/\w+/)`. To try it, first create a file: `File.write("temp", "Now is\nthe time\nto rejoice.") #=> 27`. Then test: `File.read("temp").scan(/\w+/) #=> ["Now", "is", "the", "time", "to", "rejoice"] `.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Either do:

```
text_file.push(*line.split.map(&:to_s))
```

or:

```
text_file.concat(line.split.map(&:to_s))
```

Comment: It seems odd converting strings to strings.

Comment: @tadman Right. `map(&:to_s)` is redundant. But that is what the OP gave, and even though it does not make sense, it still works, so I left it.

Comment: @tadman you are right, it's redundant so I'm removing it now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want all of the words, uniquely, sorted:

```
text_file = [ ]

File.open(file, "r") do |f|
  f.each_line do |line|
    text_file += line.split
  end
end

text_file.uniq!
text_file.sort!
```

This is not the most optimal implementation, but it should work. To adapt this to more real-world situations you probably need to use `String#scan` to pull out more specific words instead of getting tripped up on things like punctuation or hyphens.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying your code, this will do the trick:

```
text_file = []

File.open('document.rb', "r") do |f|
  f.each_line do |line|
    arr = line.split(' ')
    arr.each do |word|
      text_file << word
    end  
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The following reads the contents of `file`, splits lines and words delimited by spaces, and then makes a constant called `WORDS` by freezing the result.

```rb
WORDS = File.read(file).split(/[ \n]/).freeze
```

If you also want to use tabs as well as spaces and newlines as delimiters use the following:

```rb
WORDS = File.read(file).split(/[ \n\t]/).freeze
```